# read from csv file in java

Tags: java, csv

I have a huge CSV file.I have to read it and store in a database using java.below code only read about 2000 rows from that file and store it into database.why? note the below calculation is to change the seconds to minutes with approximation.dont think a lot about that

```
import com.opencsv.CSVReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ReadCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{

        MainController mc = new MainController();
        boolean status=false; 

        String csvFile = "C:/Users/Thanushiya/Desktop/mobios/internship/csvfile/csvfile/Master.csv";
        CSVReader  reader = null;
        List myList = new ArrayList();
        String[] row = null;
        int duration_m = 0;
        try {
            reader = new CSVReader (new FileReader(csvFile), ',', '\'', 17);
            myList = reader.readAll();
            int i=0;
                for (Object object : myList) {
                    row = (String[]) object;
                    float duration_float = Float.parseFloat(row[12]) / 60 ;
                    float duration_mod = duration_float % 1 ;

                    if(Integer.parseInt(row[12]) <= 60){
                        duration_m = 1;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(duration_mod == 0 ){
                            duration_m = (int) duration_float;
                        }
                        else{
                            duration_m = ((int) duration_float) + 1;
                        }
                    }
                    String query = "INSERT INTO master(msisdn,serv,start,end,ringwithdurartion,duration_s,status,cid,duration_m) values ('"+row[0]+"','"+row[4]+"','"+row[8]+"','"+row[10]+"','"+row[11]+"','"+row[12]+"','"+row[13]+"','"+row[15]+"','"+duration_m+"')";
                    status=mc.insertData(query);

                }//end for

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens at the 2001 line?

Comment: there is no issue there.only reads 200 line and finished running.

Comment: Please add a generic catch all exception handler, perhaps there is some data which cause this issue. (How many lines are in the csv file?)

Answer (score 4):

With `readAll()` you're loading (or at least trying to load) the entire file into memory at once. That will severely limit the number of lines you can read before running out of memory. As indicated on the [OpenCSV homepage](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/), there's also an iterator that reads line per line:

```
 CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/Thanushiya/Desktop/mobios/internship/csvfile/csvfile/Master.csv"), ',', '\'', 17);
 String [] nextLine;
 while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
    // put the code from your for loop here
 }
```

Comment: Anything special that's visible in a regular text editor? One nasty case I've encountered where reading just stopped like that was where different line terminators were being used (probably due to the file being stitched together sub reports). Btw, even if you're not running out of memory reading the file line by line is a better solution that just reading everything at once.

Comment: not special.I wrote the query for a count in my SQL yog..There also seems 2000 lines will be there

Comment: Soory for this question.The error is on editor.IT is set as limit lines view.